# How to recover data when only fastboot mode?

Tags: fastboot, oneplus, oneplus-6

I have oneplus 6, it stuck on QUALCOMM CRASHDUMP MODE. I'm able to load into fastboot and recovery mode. The device is not rooted (locked).

I tried to change slot using fastboot cli, but it say that I need to unlock it.

I don't want to loose that data. How can I recover the data without wiping it?

Comment: Regular Fastboot implementation only have commands for writing data and stock recovery also misses functions for reading data. The only way would be to reflash the original system firmware via recover if it provides the function `adb sideload`.

Comment: won't it erase the data on my phone? how can I know what is the original system firmware?

Comment: If the firmware to be installed has the same signature as the installed firmware this should be possible without factory reset. The procedure is the same as if you would receive an OTA update. Note that this is only possible via `adb sideload` (or a different manufacturer specific installation system) but not via fastboot.

Comment: ok, how can I get the installation file (image) with the same signature?

Comment: That depends on the manufacturer and the concrete phone model.

Comment: ok, how do I check all of those? how do I get the version?

Comment: Typically smartphone users know the manufacturer and phone type they use. And the version should be the latest available for your country.